# Learning Bayesian Networks

Tags: machine-learning

I have data but the problem with this data does not ordering and I want to learn the structure from this data.The problem is each time I change the order of the attribute  the structure change. can any one suggest library or algorithm doesn't effect by the order of the input data.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no, probably not.

Long answer - 
There are two reasons why this is hard.  The first is that Bayes net structure isn't always identifiable.  The second is that, by ordering the variables, you are constraining the set of structures that are feasible.  I'm not sure what method you are using, but they are probably doing some kind of search-and-score that finds local optima in the likelihood of network structure and parameters for the networks that are consistent with your ordering.

This all means that the structure that you learn is going to be sensitive to the ordering that you impose.  A model that doesn't impose that ordering (like a markov/conditional random field) might make more sense.